# Zurb Foundation topbar menu bar dropdown not working (the phone size one)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

Most people are talking about dropdown menus when the bar is expanded
I'm talking about menu when you adjust the browser window to a phone size. 
You should be able to over menu and the list of items should drop down 
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html 
The code is from this page, (second example). If you re adjust it should show menu and drop down items.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
        <script src="js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gideon Sassoon</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
      </li>    
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href=""><span>Menu</span>
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Nav Button Active</a></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
            <a href="#">Right Button with Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
    <script>$(document).foundation();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Okay so the code is correct, I've checked it and a friend has as well. 
To clarify I DO NOT mean the Right Button with dropdown. That works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you expect the topbar menu button in "mobile mode" to drop down when hovering over here

[image]

with the mouse.

In that case, the topbar works as designed - there is no hover on mobile touch devices, so it only reacts to touch/click when in mobile mode.

**Edit:**

I now understand your problem to be that clicking the "Menu" toggle reloads the page. It seems like you forgot to include the Foundation topbar script:

```
<script src="js/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have clicked it. It responds incorrectly.
`<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="">` The `#` is the issue. As it just reloads the page. But in comparison, they have the same and it does not. Also their example does respond within my browser. Which is where I have been testing mine. So it should work.

Comment: @GideonSassoon what do you mean by 'responds incorrectly'? How does it respond?

Comment: As in the menu should drop down but instead it just reloads the page.
Apologies about the late edit I was unaware I had to use Shift+Return to make a new line.

Comment: I added it in between these lines as such and it had no effect.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">`
`<script src="js/foundation.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>`
`<script src="js/foundation.topbar.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>`

Comment: @GideonSassoon please create a jsFiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I'm uncertain as to how creating it would change anything?
I think it would make it more complicated since I would have to reference the javascript and Css that I did not create.

Comment: In order for me to help you, I will have to take a look at it myself. If you host your problematic code somewhere else, that would of course be just as good.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I think I have just resolved the same problem you were seeing so I am adding this answer for anyone else out there who comes across it.

For me, the problem was that I was trying to override the height of the top-bar element in my CSS. Once I removed this entry my top-bar functioned correctly on small screens

```
.top-bar {
    height: 3em;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Same here. Fixed an issue on mobile chrome. The toggle would work on safari mobile and all desktop web clients, but not on chrome mobile (38.0.2125.59).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it with:

```
$('.left-off-canvas-toggle').on('click', function(){});
```